# $viewContentLoaded isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

`$viewContentLoaded` never fires in my Angular controller. The following:

```
function MyController($scope)
{
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function()
    {
        alert("blah");
    });
}
```

Never hits a breakpoint, and never pops up the alert. I think this is pretty standard use, so I'm not sure what it could be, but it's definitely not firing. Everything else in the controller is behaving properly.

What would cause this?

Comment: Anything in the error console?

Comment: @MikePateras Are you initiating the controller in your view?

Comment: Jordan, nothing in the console (no errors or warnings at all). RickCigarette, I'm binding it in the html via ng-controller, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Where in the HTML are you including this controller via ng-controller and where is your <ng-view>?

Comment: The div that has the controller is the first child of the ng-view element.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Base on your comment above, it sounds like you have something like this:

```
<ng-view>
   <div ng-controller="MyController"></div>
</ng-view>
```

I'm not sure what content in the ng-view tag will do, but the `$viewContentLoaded` is *emitted* from the ng-view scope. This means, it only goes up from the `ng-view` and thus your controller would never catch it.

Comment: Yup, just figured that out myself, and indeed it works when the controller is outside of ng-view. Turns out what I wanted was includeContentLoaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Try this instead:

```
  function MyController($scope)
    {
        $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function()
        {
            alert("blah");
        });
    }
```

Comment: this does not work. DOM is not yet rendered with css applied yet. I had to wrap `alert('blah')` in `$timeout(fn, 0)` to get a fully rendered page. The view is loaded by has not been parsed by angular yet.

Comment: chovy, yea. depends on what you are trying to do. you may have to do this instead if you want to wait for css to load etc. $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
         $timeout(function () {
       alert("blah blah");
      }, 500);
        });

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by specifying the controller in the app.js route provider rather than using ng-controller in a div in the view. I only use this method if I need to use $viewContentLoaded, otherwise I use ng-controller.

```
angular.module('myapp', [...])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/MyRoute', {templateUrl: 'views/MyView.html', controller: MyController})
  });
```