# Angularjs: Get function fired when side completly renderd

Tags: angularjs

I have to finish a webpage which has a lot of jQuery and AngularJS in it. There are gestures and lots of fx and stuff, so it makes sense, but I'm not thinking to do that in Angluar, but for the future I will think more Angular.

What I just want is, that my `init();` function is fired when everthing is ready.

I use two Controller both with a JSON call.

When I put just `init();` into  the `.then` of the http call then it's not renderd yet.

I use two controllers, on 3 areas on the website. So it gets fired 3 times, when I put it in both controllers.

I found

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    //call it here
});
```

that would be nice, but its not working, or I don't know how to implement it.

**How can I get this running?**

When I put in the `Controllerfunction` it has no errors but doesn't fire.

`data-ng-init` also doesn't do the trick.

Is there a fE. the ng-repeat is done or kind like this.

Comment: did you have a ng-view in you app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$viewContentLoaded isn't firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223819/viewcontentloaded-isnt-firing)

Comment: `$viewContentLoaded` is not a paneacea for everything's ready like `$(document).ready` is for jQuery. Need to how what you are trying to do with your `init()`. Likely need to call it from within a directive

Comment: I have no ng-view, thats a otherthing which confuses me, for me it would be obvious to have more than 1 view on an app.

Comment: sounds like you need to go step by step through tutorial on docs site