# AngularJS - ngRoute - Callback after view-load finished

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, callback

I try to implement an Animation-Dialog with AngularJS. So my APP starts and Shows an Dialog (all is well so on), but that Dialog contains Images wich are out of viewport (becaus I move them out of viewport with my CSS) and then should animate in, when the Dialog opened up and it's Contents where loaded.

Thatfor I attached an class to the Images, so they are out of viewport. While removing the class, the animate into the viewport. All well so on.

BUT: How do I get AngularJS let them animate in, after this Dialog opened up?

Heres the dialgs HTML, for Debugging I added the {{closed}} and the hyperlink:

```
<div class="dialog bg-turkey" id="mainpage">
<img src="images/mainpage-1.png" id="mainpage-1" ng-class="{unanimated: closed}">
<img src="images/mainpage-2.png" id="mainpage-2" ng-class="{unanimated: closed}">
<img src="images/mainpage-3.png" id="mainpage-3" ng-class="{unanimated: closed}">
<img src="images/mainpage-4.png" id="mainpage-4" ng-class="{unanimated: closed}">

{{closed}}

<a ng-click='animate()'>open</a>
</div>
```

Here's the dialogs Controller:

```
var loadingController = ["$scope", function ($scope) {
$scope.closed = true;

$scope.animate = function () {
    alert('los');
    $scope.closed = false;
};

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    setTimeout(
        $scope.animate,
        100
    );
});
}];
```

and here's the route:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    controller:   loadingController,
    templateUrl:  'views/loading.html'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: "views/welcome.html"
});
});
```

Now on opening up that Dialog, the aleart (debugging purposes) appears, but the variable doesn't Change. Just while I click the Hyperlink, the alert appears ant the variable changes and then the Animation starts..

What do I do wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223819/viewcontentloaded-isnt-firing might help

Comment: it does not help :/ seems like the scope is an other one, so I don't modify the correct instance of the variable

Comment: Weird-- I'm not sure what your issue is. I copied the main parts of your code into a plunkr and it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/aH3GXxJbkJoIkwgqPx0A?p=preview

Comment: hey Chad, it's about starting an CSS Animation, not just displaying an alert-box :) And th Animation has to be delayed through an timeout because else there is no animation visible :) see on my reply at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it this way:

```
var loadingController = ["$scope", function ($scope) {
$scope.opened = false;

setTimeout(
    function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.opened = true;
        });
    },
    100
);
}];
```

Thanks for this post: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html