# Weird behavior of $viewContentLoaded in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am writing a **jquery** code which I needed to be executed right after my template view got loaded and DOM gets modified.

I am using `$viewContentLoaded`  **event** in my **controller** for this purpose.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
    page_content_onresize();  
});
```

But unfortunately `$viewContentLoaded` didn't worked for me.

As my code needs to be applied right after **DOM gets modified** after loading of template in its view **but everything was working fine when I wasn't using that ng-view and was loading my html directly without using any template**.

I tried everything but I didn't get my script run properly using `$viewContentLoaded`.

So I changed my code to something like this and everything was working perfect then.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
    setTimeout(page_content_onresize, 0);

});
```

**I did't Understand why it wasn't working in the first case?**

```
function page_content_onresize(){
    $(".page-content,.content-frame-body,.content-frame-right,.content-frame-left").css("width","").css("height","");

    var content_minus = 0;
    content_minus = ($(".page-container-boxed").length > 0) ? 40 : content_minus;
    content_minus += ($(".page-navigation-top-fixed").length > 0) ? 50 : 0;

    var content = $(".page-content");
    var sidebar = $(".page-sidebar");

    if(content.height() < $(document).height() - content_minus){        
        content.height($(document).height() - content_minus);
    }        

    if(sidebar.height() > content.height()){        
        content.height(sidebar.height());
    }

    if($(window).width() > 1024){

        if($(".page-sidebar").hasClass("scroll")){
            if($("body").hasClass("page-container-boxed")){
                var doc_height = $(document).height() - 40;
            }else{
                var doc_height = $(window).height();
            }
            $(".page-sidebar").height(doc_height);

        }

        if($(".content-frame-body").height() < $(document).height()-162){
            $(".content-frame-body,.content-frame-right,.content-frame-left").height($(document).height()-162);            
        }else{
            $(".content-frame-right,.content-frame-left").height($(".content-frame-body").height());
        }

        $(".content-frame-left").show();
        $(".content-frame-right").show();
    }else{
        $(".content-frame-body").height($(".content-frame").height()-80);

        if($(".page-sidebar").hasClass("scroll"))
               $(".page-sidebar").css("height","");
    }

    if($(window).width() < 1200){
        if($("body").hasClass("page-container-boxed")){
            $("body").removeClass("page-container-boxed").data("boxed","1");
        }
    }else{
        if($("body").data("boxed") === "1"){
            $("body").addClass("page-container-boxed").data("boxed","");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @mohamedrias no error showing on console.

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223819/viewcontentloaded-isnt-firing

Comment: @mohamedrias Na that not the case. controller is **catching**  `$viewContentLoaded` and `$viewContentLoaded` **event** is getting called. But some how I think DOM is not getting modified at time when this event is  getting called and possibly thats why its is working when using setTimeout function within `$viewContentLoaded`.

Comment: I highly recommend moving your jQuery code into a directive, so that you can guarantee that it will fire at the right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$viewContentLoaded` event will be fired once the template is loaded.
It will not guarantee that the loaded template is rendered on the page.

**code snippet from angular.js**

```
var clone = $transclude(newScope, function(clone) {
  $animate.enter(clone, null, currentElement || $element).then(function onNgViewEnter() {
    if (angular.isDefined(autoScrollExp)
      && (!autoScrollExp || scope.$eval(autoScrollExp))) {
      $anchorScroll();
    }
  });
  cleanupLastView();
});

currentElement = clone;
currentScope = current.scope = newScope;
currentScope.$emit('$viewContentLoaded');
currentScope.$eval(onloadExp);
```

**code snippet from ngAnimate.js**

```
enter: function(element, parentElement, afterElement, options) {
  options = parseAnimateOptions(options);
  element = angular.element(element);
  parentElement = prepareElement(parentElement);
  afterElement = prepareElement(afterElement);

  classBasedAnimationsBlocked(element, true);
  $delegate.enter(element, parentElement, afterElement);
  return runAnimationPostDigest(function(done) {
    return performAnimation('enter', 'ng-enter', stripCommentsFromElement(element), parentElement, afterElement, noop, options, done);
  });
}
```

**$animate.enter is not synchronous.**

Because of this, `$viewContentLoaded` is emitted first and then the content is rendered on to the page.